# AuthUserFile not working, what could be wrong?

Tags: authentication, centos, httpd.conf, .htpasswd

I'm using CentOS
and I switched servers last night.
I'm having a problem with the `AuthUserFile` file.

I always get blocked.
I made sure that:

1. The path is the real path:

   ```
   AuthUserFile /home/rootvideo/.htpasswd
   ```
2. The `/home/rootvideo/.htpasswd` and `.htaccess` file has `0644` permissions.
3. `httpd.conf` is set to `AllowOverride All` in all of the folders.
4. All the `mod_auth` are loaded.

   ```
   LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
   LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
   LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
   LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
   LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
   LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
   ```

Any ideas?

Comment: What messages do you get in your server's `error.log` or `access.log`?

Comment: from the access_log i get :
193.106.55.249 - - [25/Oct/2011:08:22:23 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 478 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1"
from the error_log
[Tue Oct 25 08:24:49 2011] [error] [client 193.106.55.249] (13)Permission denied: Could not open password file: /home/rootvideo/.htpasswd
[Tue Oct 25 08:24:49 2011] [error] [client 193.106.55.249] access to /index.php failed, reason: verification of user id 'user' not configured
tried even to chmod  777 /home/rootvideo/.htpasswd and still get the same messege

Comment: SOLVED!!!! the problem was the father directoriy need premisitions to be set to chmod 755! that solved the problem, thanks all!

Comment: I am having the same problem, but I have looked at my error_log file, and i see (13)Permission Denied: Could not open password file, BUT i have CHMOD 0644 the passwd file and CHMOD 0755 the parent dir, and CHOWN -R apache:apache parent/dir, i have no other ammunition left!

Answer (score 4):

For future reference :

Chmodd the file to 0660 the parent directory to 0755 and the owner of the file should be the apache user. For debian variants (ubuntu) this is www-data. For CentOS its apache.

```
chmod 0660 /mylocation/.htpasswd
chmod 0775 /mylocation
# centOS
chown apache:apache /mylocation/.htpasswd
# ubuntu
chown www-data:www-data /mylocation/.htpasswd
```

Finding what user you need :

```
grep -e '^User' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
grep -e '^User' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Comment: I think it is not a requirement that Apache user is the owner of the directories and files. In my working setup all this stuff belongs to the user who performs the deployment. Suffice it that Apache should have `rx` on directories and `r` on files.

Answer (score 1):

Just have to add my experience here with this issue. In my case I was working on a recent Centos server that had SELinux enabled. I was getting permissions denied errors on my .htpasswd file even though all the permissions were set like they should.

I ended up just disabling SELinux, as it was an internal server only, but the best solution is ofcourse change the SELinux setup to allow read access to this file for the apache webuser.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue.  In my case, I had made a typo and written AuthType instead of AuthName in my configuration.  The AuthType was thus overriden by an invalid value.  For others who encounter this it's worth double checking whether you have any incorrect AuthType directives in your conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and my issue was from an "invisible character".

I've deleted the whole line of `AuthUserFile`, and wrote again (this time, not copy pasting) and it's fixed!

Answer (score -1):

For my the problem was that I had `Require all granted` in the section resulting in the directory was not proteced with any password.

After removing it the password authentication works.

Note: I was using WebDAV together with password authentication on apache2 2.4.7 on ubuntu